# detect input from multiple opton in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am building rating system with css.

My html code is:

```
<div class="rating">
    <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" />
    <label for="star5" title="Awesome..!">5 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" />
    <label for="star4" title="Pretty good">4 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" />
    <label for="star3" title="Ok!">3 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" />
    <label for="star2" title="Kinda bad">2 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" />
    <label for="star1" title="poor!">1 star</label>
</div>
```

and jQuery is:

```
$(function () {
    $("div:has(input)").on("click", function (e) {
        var value = $(":radio").attr('value');
        alert(value);
    });
});
```

please [refer this JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CGP87/1664/)

currently `var value` is printing only **5** in clicking on any start. but i want precise Value in my output.

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/PSYKLON/CGP87/1668/

Answer (score 2):

try

```
$(function () {
    $("div :input").on("click", function (e) {
        var value = this.value;
        alert(value);

    });
});
```

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CGP87/1665/)**

Comment: responds with 'undefined'. can you help it on [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CGP87/1664/)

Comment: @BomberMan Why can't you check the difference with the demo given by the answerer.??

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy i miss observed! its working :)

Comment: @BomberMan That's good to hear. Now, try to accept anyone of the answers present here which satisfies your need. And this is not a mandatory thing. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function () {
    $(":radio").on("click", function (e) {

        var value = $(this).val();
        alert(value);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to get value of clicked rating star

```
$(function () {
    $(".rating :input").on("click", function (e) {
        var value = this.value;
        alert(value);
    });
});
```